# The usage of "to corral"

Tags: usage

Is it grammatically correct and idiomatic to use the verb [corral](https://www.lexico.com/definition/corral) as the following example

> I corralled all my notes/findings in the book.

Answer (score 2):

No. It is grammatically correct and a possible sentence in English, but it is not idiomatic to use “corral” in this way for inert items like notes.

The reason is that “corral” carries with it a strong sense that the items, people or animals being corralled would escape or disperse if it wasn’t for the actions involved in “corralling” them. This sort of meaning doesn’t sit well with notes and findings, unless there was some supporting context, such as:

> I became pretty disorganised with so much going on.  I had terrible trouble keeping my notes together. Every  time I returned to them they seemed to have been strewn all around the office. I eventually corralled all my notes and findings securely in a series of folders, and then felt ready to start work on the book.

Answer (score 0):

The grammar is fine.

Your choice of **corral** as the verb, presumably meaning **gathered/arranged/ordered/organised** is unusual but fair enough if you wish to compare gathering your notes to corralling domestic animals.

When you say **on the book** do you mean **concerning the book** or **in the book**? The former meaning is suggested.

Comment: I meant " in the book."